# Подсчет среднего балла группы

Tags: c

У меня есть массив `student_list`, каждый элемент которого является записью о студенте:

```
// группа | фио |  оценки
"4272 Галкин Г. А. 5445",
"4273 Константинопольский А. А. 4333",
"4273 Курочкин А. А. 3433",
"4272 Козлов И. И. 4443"
```

Мне нужно подсчитать средний балл каждой группы, а именно получить в данном случае два числа:

- `(5 + 4 + 4 + 5) + (4 + 4 + 4 + 3) = 33 / 2 = 16.5`
- `(4 + 3 + 3 + 3) + (3 + 4 + 3 + 3) = 26 / 2 = 13`

Моя функция на данный момент имеет вид:

```
void group_average_scope() {
  char name[50];
  int group;
  int exam;

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    int sum_of_evaluations = 0;
    int digit = 0;
    int counter_digits = 0;

    sscanf(student_list[i], "%d %[^0-9] %d", &group, name, &exam);

    while (exam > 0) {
      digit = exam % 10;
      sum_of_evaluations += digit;
      counter_digits++;
      exam = exam / 10;
    }
  }
}
```

Подскажите, как находить номер группы и оценку.

Answer (score 2):

Можно, к примеру:
1) создать список групп, элементами в котором будет структурка, содержащая номер группы, средний балл группы, общий балл всех студентов группы, количество студентов группы:

```
struct group{
  int gpoup_num;
  float score;
  int all_stud_score;
  int stud_cnt;
  struct group *next;
};
```

2) после того, как общая оценка студента подсчитана, произвести поиск его группы(предусмотрительно Вами считанной в scanf()) в списке групп по номеру, тут 2 варианта :

1. если номер не найден, - добавить
       группу в список, не забыв сохранить
       полученный общий балл студента в
       `all_stud_score` данной группы, и
       установив число студентов группы в
       1;
2. если номер группы найден, общий
           балл студента добавляется к текущему
           значению `all_stud_score` группы, а
           количество студентов группы увеличивается на 1;

3) после того, как все записи о студентах считаны, осуществляется проход по списку имеющихся групп, общий балл всех студентов группы `all_stud_score` делится на количество студентов данной группы `stud_cnt` и сохряняется в среднем балле группы `score`.

Если Вы работаете с С и еще не знакомы со списками, информацию о них можно найти, к примеру, вот [тут](http://lord-n.narod.ru/download/books/walla/programming/Spr_po_C/22/2205.htm), в С++ можно использовать `vector` или другие контейнеры.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно просто напечатать статистику, то достаточно отсортировать студенческие записи по номеру группы и считать средний бал на лету, начиная новую группу, если прочитанный номер группы не совпадает с номером из предыдущей строчки.

Основной цикл:

```
  qsort(student_list, n, sizeof(student_list[0]), cmpstringp);

  for (pstudent = student_list; pstudent != &student_list[n]; ++pstudent) {
    int group = -1, scores = -1;
    char *name = NULL;

    errno = 0;
    if (sscanf(*pstudent, "%d %m[^0-9] %d", &group, &name, &scores) != 3) {
      if (errno) perror("sscanf");
      fprintf(stderr, "error: can't parse '%s'\n", *pstudent);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (group != last_group) {
      if (group_count > 0) /* print the last group average score */
        printf("%d %f\n", last_group, (double)group_score/group_count);

      group_score = 0; /* start new group */
      group_count = 0;
      last_group = group;
    }
    ++group_count;
    group_score += get_score(scores);
    free(name);
  }
  if (group_count > 0) /* print the last group average score */
    printf("%d %f\n", last_group, (double)group_score/group_count);
```

[Результат](http://ideone.com/2mUfBE)

```
4272 4.125000
4273 3.250000
```

Ответ отличается на множитель `4` потому что я определил `get_score()` функцию возвращать средную оценку вместо суммы оценок за экзамен. Деление можно убрать, если это не нужно.

Цикл реализует `groupby()` алгоритм из стандартной библиотеки Питона, вот тоже самое, где `groupby()` вызывается явно:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys
from itertools import groupby

student_list = [
    # группа | фио | оценки
    "4272 Галкин Г. А. 5445",
    "4273 Константинопольский А. А. 4333",
    "4273 Курочкин А. А. 3433",
    "4272 Козлов И. И. 4443"
]

def get_score(scores):
    """'5445' -> (5 + 4 + 4 + 5) / 4 -> 4.5"""
    return sum(map(float, scores)) / len(scores)

for _, students in groupby(sorted(student_list), key=lambda s: s.split()[0]):
    group_score = 0
    for group_count, s in enumerate(students, start=1):
        try:
            group, scores = re.match(r'(\d+).*?(\d+)', s).groups()
        except ValueError:
            sys.exit("error: can't parse %r" % s)
        else:
            group_score += get_score(scores)
    print("%s %f" % (group, group_score / group_count))
```

Результаты идентичны (тот же вывод).