# Запись и считывание из файла структуры

Tags: c++, файлы, структуры, запись

Моё задание на C++
Составить программу "Список студентов группы", в котором указаны - Фамилия,Имя,пол, место рождения, год рождения.
Создать файл со студентами.
Нужно сформировать новые файлы, потом их упорядочить:
1)Список юношей,родившихся в городе название которого вводится с клавиатуры
2)Список девушек
3)Список студентов, родившихся в году, который вводится с клавиатуры.

---

Мой вопрос такой- Как мне сделать чтение из файла чтобы потом можно было работать в консоли.Без записи и чтения в файл у меня все работает. В меню я сделал чтение, она читает НО читает как то криво и не правильно.
вот само чтение моей структуры 
char f2[20], c;
        FILE *v;

```
    cout << "\nВведите имя файла для чтения: ";

    //fscanf(v, "%d", &m); 
    cin >> f2;

    v = fopen(f2, "r");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        fscanf(v, "%s%s%s%d%d%d%s", &student[i].Family, &student[i].Name, &student[i].Sex, &student[i].Date[0], &student[i].Date[1], &student[i].Date[2], &student[i].City);
    cout<< "\nЧтение из файла "<< f2<< ":\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        cout << student[i].Family << " " << student[i].Name << " " << student[i].Sex << " " << student[i].Date[0] << "." << student[i].Date[1] << "." << student[i].Date[2] << " " << student[i].City; //<< "\n";
    system("pause");
```

Вот что получается [image: введите сюда описание изображения] (P.s у Тани забыл город ввести), но сути не меняет. Почему то после чтения Васи, опять считываются данные Васи.

Comment: У меня возникает подозрение, что %d в scanf - чтение ОДНОГО десятичного числа, у вас же даты, судя по всему, пишутся совсем не одним числом... Вывод \n после каждой записи определенно поможет понять тут проблема или нет...

Comment: хм, спасибо сейчас попробую

Comment: у меня записываются они так 
 cin >> Date[0]; fprintf(f, "%d.", Date[0]);
 gotoxy(55, 4);
 cin.ignore(); 
 cin >> Date[1]; fprintf(f, "%d.", Date[1]);
 gotoxy(58, 4);

 cin >> Date[2]; fprintf(f, "%d\n", Date[2]);
 cin.ignore();

Comment: А не, тремя числами вы их пишете...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов спасибо большое, получилось. Блин, теперь правда еще куча вопросов, хах)

Comment: А что получилось-то? В чем дело было?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов ну я сделал как вы сказали \n 
из за того что то были 3 числа.

Comment: Похожий вопрос: [Подсчет среднего балла группы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/386482/23044)

Comment: Так это, можете сделать самоответ, может кто ещё и плюсик-другой ему отвесит.